# Finding memory Leak in COM dll using glowcode tool

Tags: memory-leaks

In Windows, please any one can help me to find out the memory leak using GlowCode Tool.
I am trying to add the dll but m not able to find  the proper function or class where exactly memory getting leak. we are created  COM DLL and we written some function and trying to export those functions in to VC++ mfc dll Application.

please provide how to use the GLowCode tool when we need to find the memory leak in com dll

Advance Thanks
Manohar Kumar A

Answer (score 0):

There is a help document associated with GlowCode. It has step by step guide to use Glowcode. Have you tried that?

Comment: This idn't an answer. It may be helpful, but it woud make a better comment.